# Why is my instance variable showing up on the view when I never called it explicitly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I'm coding on rails and I have created an application from the `rails g model` and `rails g controller` I have successfully created the index, show, create and new actions and after running my server and checking my finished project I have this problem where my instance variable of `@coupons` which contains an array of the created coupons, is showing up in the views index page. I didn't call it explicitly or anything it just showed up. Below is my code for my `index.html.erb` and `CouponController`.

views/index.html.erb

```
<h1> List of Stores with Coupons</h1>

<div>
<%= @coupons.each do |coupon| %>
  <h2><%= link_to coupon.store, coupon_path(coupon) %></h2>
<% end %>
</div>

<%= form_tag new_coupon_path, :method => :get do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Create New Coupon" %>
<% end %>
```

CouponController

```
class CouponsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @coupons = Coupon.all
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @coupon = Coupon.create(coupon_code: params[:coupon][:coupon_code], store: params[:coupon][:store])

    redirect_to coupon_path(@coupon)
  end

  def show
    @coupon = Coupon.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Note that I also deleted the CSS that came when I created the controller from `rails g controller` [image: Image of said issue]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= @coupons.each do |coupon| %>
```

should be

```
<% @coupons.each do |coupon| %>
```

The `<%=` causes `@coupons` to be output on the view.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `<%= %>` and not `<% %>`.

`<%= %>` outputs the value of an expression. The return value of `#each` is an array.

```
<% @coupons.each do |coupon| %>
  <h2><%= link_to coupon.store, coupon_path(coupon) %></h2>
<% end %>
```

This can be somewhat confusing but remember that you are using `#each` for the side effects - and not the return value. For each iteration `<h2><%= link_to coupon.store, coupon_path(coupon) %></h2>` is added to the string buffer (the rendered view).

Comment: Ther you go, using all them fancy words! (Nicely done.)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks!